# Slick slider change bg image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the code below:
I use slick slider for creating a slider with background images instead of using img tag. My slider height is 700px and min-height is 400px.
With the jquery code below i want to change the background image depending on the window width, but the problem is that the code changes just the image from the first slider. Any help ? :) Thank you

```
<div class="hero-slider-wraper">
 <div class="hero-slider">
  <div class="hero-slider-component">
   <div class="hero-slider-image" data-img-mobile="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home1-small.jpg" data-img-large="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home1.jpg" ></div>
   <div class="hero-slider-image" data-img-mobile="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home2-small.jpg" data-img-large="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home2.jpg"></div>
   <div class="hero-slider-image" data-img-mobile="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home3-small.jpg" data-img-large="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/home3.jpg"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

function resizeSlick() {
    var desktopImage = $('.slick-current').attr("data-img-large");
    var mobileImage = $('.slick-current').attr("data-img-mobile");

if($(window).width() < 768)
{
        $('.slick-current').css('background-image', 'url("'+ mobileImage +'")');
}
else
{
        $('.slick-current').css('background-image', 'url("'+ desktopImage +'")');
}
}

    //initialize
    resizeSlick();

    //call when the page resizes.
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeSlick();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the code for each image and not just the `.slick-current`

```js
function resizeSlick() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  $('.hero-slider-image').each(function() {
    var desktopImage = $('.slick-current').attr("data-img-large"),
        mobileImage = $('.slick-current').attr("data-img-mobile");

    if (windowWidth < 768) {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("' + mobileImage + '")');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("' + desktopImage + '")');
    }

  });
}

//initialize
resizeSlick();

//call when the page resizes.
$(window).resize(resizeSlick);
```